# Workflow to checkout single node package for developing a patch / pull request

Tags: node.js, git, yarnpkg

I want to add a feature to https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-react-redux/ which is pulled in from the https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-ui/tree/master/packages/geocoder package (add another geocoder).

Coming from the PHP world and composer, I normally do in such cases

```
composer install
rm -r vendor/foo/bar
composer install --prefer-source
cd vendor/foo/bar
git remote set-url origin <myforkURL>
git checkout main
```

Now I can easily edit that package in-place and make a pull request.

My question is: Is there a similar work-flow possible for node packages using yarn?

I already tried

```
yarn add "@opentripplanner/geocoder#master"
```

but no `.git` folder appeared in `otp-react-redux/node_modules/@opentripplanner` or `otp-react-redux/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder`

Also it looks like that multiple packages are created from the `@opentripplanner` repo, which might complicate things.

I could try to simply edit the files in `node_modules` and then copy them to the a manually checked-out git repository, but when running `yarn start` everything is also overwritten.

EDIT: As the packages come from a monorepo I tried to delete all the `@opentripplanner` lines from `packages.json` and added:

`yarn add opentripplanner/otp-ui#main`

This now causes the build to fail.
I noticed, that the base package.json requires different package versions from the monorepo, so it will not work to require the complete the full main branch.

EDIT2: I found some clue here:

https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-ui#development

but that also caused dependencies to not resolve properly.

EDIT3: `yarn link` actually looked promissing:

```
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-ui
cd otp-ui/packages/geocoder
yarn link
```

Now in the main project code (otp-react-redux)

```
yarn link "@opentripplanner/geocoder"
```

This creates a symlink in the node_modules folder to the specific folder in the monorepo I have cloned.

Unfortunately the build does not work:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@opentripplanner/geocoder' in 'otp-react-redux/lib/actions'
```

I even tried to match the version which is used in the main project by checking out the [revision of 1.2.1](https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-ui/commit/4124ac1691ebe97ed8280472a03fd8b7acac0db1)

Comment: That has nothing to do with PHP, node or whatever language. If @opentripplanner is a monorepo containing multiple packages in one repository, the only thing you can do is fork that repo, make your changes and create a pll request ... Many repos also provide docs on how to contribute.

Comment: Yes, the question is about the package management

Comment: Why not just check out the whole repository as it is and leave the things you don't want to change untouched? Why do you insist on deleting something which is part of the repo from your working copy?

Comment: I don't insist on anything ... ?!

Comment: You seem to keep asking how to delete certain parts from that monorepo. And if it's about how to contribute to one specific repository, it's probably best to ask the maintainers of that repository

Comment: Probably a misunderstanding, out of my confusion :-) I just want to find a way to edit the the geocoder package to later make a pull request and test it in-place during development in the otp-react-redux project.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn link` does the job!

```
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/opentripplanner/otp-ui
cd otp-ui
yarn
cd packages/geocoder
yarn link
```

Now in the main project code (otp-react-redux)

```
yarn link "@opentripplanner/geocoder"
```

This creates a symlink in the node_modules folder to the specific folder in the monorepo I have cloned.

To make the build work, the important part is that we run `yarn` in the monorepo before!

EDIT: Unfortunately the link process needs to be repeated for each of the `@opentripplanner` modules which require geocoder:

```
cd node_modules
$ find -name geocoder -type d 
./trip-details/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./vehicle-rental-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./transitive-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./endpoints-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./zoom-based-markers/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./trip-viewer-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./trip-form/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./transit-vehicle-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./itinerary-body/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./icons/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./route-viewer-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./printable-itinerary/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./stop-viewer-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./stops-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./location-field/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
./park-and-ride-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
```

```
cd trip-details
yarn link "@opentripplanner/geocoder"
```

repeat for each of them until they are all links:

```
otp-react-redux$ find node_modules/ -name geocoder -type l 
node_modules/@opentripplanner/trip-details/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/vehicle-rental-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/transitive-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/endpoints-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/zoom-based-markers/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/trip-viewer-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/trip-form/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/transit-vehicle-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/itinerary-body/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/icons/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/route-viewer-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/printable-itinerary/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/stop-viewer-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/stops-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/location-field/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/park-and-ride-overlay/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/base-map/node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
node_modules/@opentripplanner/geocoder
```

Answer (score 0):

[yalc](https://%20https://github.com/wclr/yalc) seems a good solution for this kind of problem

```
cd ~/projects/otp-ui/packages/itinerary-body
yarn tsc
yalc publish

cd ~/projects/otp-react-redux
yalc link @opentripplanner/itinerary-body
```

Now each time you change something in the package:

```
cd ~/projects/otp-ui/packages/itinerary-body
yarn tsc && yalc publish
cd ~/projects/otp-react-redux
yalc update
yarn start
```